# How to test Symfony FOSRestBundle routes by using Postman. How to configure FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony

Good day. 
Git [repository](https://bitbucket.org/fonjeekay/resttest/src/fe118b493c01b70c570a6997db100e4eb4d36358/project2/?at=master).
I have next routes but i can't get results of this routes.
`php console debug:route`

```
_wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_info             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}            
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  get_users_all              GET      ANY      ANY    /v1/users/all.{_format}            
  get_user                   GET      ANY      ANY    /v1/users/{id}.{_format}
```

[image]

I need to configure config and routes but i stuck with this.
this is FOS controller file:

```
/**
 * Class UsersController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 */
class UsersController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @View(serializerGroups={"user"})
     */
    public function getUsersAllAction()
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();

        $view = $this->view($users, 200);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }


    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @View(serializerGroups={"user"})
     */
    public function getUserAction($id)
    {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found');
        }

        $view = $this->view($user, 200);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

How to solve? I already saw all symfony documentation, and i can't understand how to configure.

Code on bitbucket (public):
`git pull https://fonjeekay@bitbucket.org/fonjeekay/resttest.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this command

```
php app/console --env=dev debug:router
```

or

```
php app/console debug:router
```

you're asking to Symfony to show you the routes available in dev environment. So if you want to call any of them you have:

```
http://host/app_dev.php/ROUTE
```

If you don't specify a front controller, you're telling Symfony to use the production environment. So to show the routes available in this environment, you must run

```
php app/console --env=prod debug:router
```

Try to call your route like this in dev environment:

```
http://HOST/app_dev.php/v1/users/1.json
```

or in prod envinroment:

```
http://HOST/v1/users/1.json
```

The left column in the output command is the unique name of the route, that you can use for example in controller or in twig template to generate the route from its name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, but you're able to display a page from your project? Try to add a route in another controller that doesn't extend the FOSRestController, a simple page that show 'Hello World'. Check the base example from symfony. Maybe you haven't configured properly the web server.

Comment: ye, its all on git now git pull https://fonjeekay@bitbucket.org/fonjeekay/resttest.git

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/fonjeekay/resttest/src/fe118b493c01b70c570a6997db100e4eb4d36358/project2/?at=master

Comment: it is about REST... i dont need hello world here ))

Answer (score 0):

1. `php app/console cache:clear --end=prod`  clear you prod environment cache.

2.
check your apache/nginx virtual host configuration, in apache it may looks like this:

    `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@net.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/symfony/web"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
        DirectoryIndex app.php
</VirtualHost>`

notice the DocumentRoot should look into /web direction